# Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" and "enum Identifier" in java

Tags: java, enums, syntax-error, tostring

im cant figure out what is wrong with my code if someone can help , why is it telling me this ? it gives me an error in toString method... why does it give me to insert enum body and identifier ? thank you

```
  import java.lang.String;

  public class Circle extends Shape {
  private double radius;

  public Circle( double theRadius ){
    super();
    if ( theRadius <= 0.0 )
        setRadius( Shape.DEFAULT_SIZE );
    else
        setRadius( theRadius );
}



public double getSurfaceArea(){

    return this.radius * this.radius * Math.PI;
}

public double getPeremeter(){
    ;
    return 2 * this.radius + Math.PI;
}

public double getRadius(){
    return this.radius;

}

public void setRadius( double theRadius ) {
    if( theRadius <= 0 )
        return;
    this.radius = theRadius;
}

@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;



     public String toString() {
         return "Circle Surface Area "+getSurfaceArea()+", Circle Peremeter "       +getPerimeter();
     }
}

@Override
public double getSizeAmount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}
   }
```

main class

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
 import java.text.DecimalFormat; 



 public class ShapeApp {


public static <RectangularPrism> void main(String[] args) {



    int x = 0;
    Triangle triangleObjects[] = new Triangle[ 3 ];

    triangleObjects[ 0 ] = new Rectangle("3.5","4.6");
    triangleObjects[ 1 ] = new Rectangle("3","2");

    triangleObjects[ 2 ] = new Circle(0);

    System.out.println( "List of all Shapes:\n" );
    do{
    try{
        for( Triangle currentTriangle : triangleObjects ) {
        String msg = currentTriangle.getSurfaceArea() +","+ currentTriangle.getPerimeter();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Message", msg, JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        x=2;
    }

    }catch(Exception e) {

    }

}while(x==1);


    }


}
```

error

```
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
Syntax error on token "String", @ expected
Syntax error, insert "enum Identifier" to complete EnumHeaderName
Syntax error, insert "EnumBody" to complete BlockStatement

at Circle.getPerimeter(Circle.java:44)
at ShapeApp.main(ShapeApp.java:80)
```

Comment: What does class Shape look like? And you are missing a bracket of getPerimeter() in class Circle, not sure if that causes all the errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at your `getPerimeter` method:

```
@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;



     public String toString() {
         return "Circle Surface Area "+getSurfaceArea()+", Circle Peremeter "
              +getPerimeter();
     }
}
```

You're trying to declare the `toString` method *within* the `getPerimeter` method.

The indentation of the code should have given you a hint about that - it's one reason why it's important to indent code appropriately. You should have:

```
@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}    

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Circle Surface Area " + getSurfaceArea() + ", Circle Perimeter "       
        + getPerimeter();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;



     public String toString() {
         return "Circle Surface Area "+getSurfaceArea()+", Circle Peremeter "       +getPerimeter();
     }
}
```

should be separated in two :

```
@Override
public double getPerimeter() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
             return "Circle Surface Area "+getSurfaceArea()+", Circle Peremeter "       +getPerimeter();
         }
```